# BASH Read PDF Interactive field and selected value

Tags: bash, pdf

I know I can use `pdfgrep` to search a PDF file for a required value, using and `awk` I get out the values I require from a PDF file, However...

The PDF contains a few rows which have interactive Yes / No radio buttons.

When I grep the PDF for those rows I get the full row including Yes & No, but I'd like to get the selected answer.

Eg:

```
pdfgrep -i "configure" test.pdf
```

returns:

```
     Site    Configure Site                                                            Yes        No
```

In this example `Yes` is the selected button in the PDF. So I would have liked it return :

```
      Site    Configure Site                                                           Yes
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the difference from the input and output?

Comment: I have not worked with PDF Forms, so I might be completely wrong about it. But I am pretty sure, the selection result is added at the end of the file, leaving the original intact. It should be a new object with reference to original object, modifying it. You can try having original, non filled PDF file and filled/selected one and make a diff compare to find, what has changed. pdfgrep would not help I am almost sure, it is very limited against the possible monstrosities in a PDF. If you open the PDF in say, Notepad++ or comparable tool, you would see an extra xref table after editing/filling.

Comment: @Jetchisel Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Please can you explain ?

Comment: @uldics I'll do a diff and see what that shows. Viewing it in notepad++ does result in anything read able apart from a small amount XML data relating to the author.

Comment: Yes, it can be with higher PDF version (first line in data), that objects themselves are encoded inside other objects. If you can save as lower version and retain forms, could help. Or do Preflight and recompile without encoded object streams. But that requires Adobe Acrobat Pro subscription. I know of no other way. Maybe, just maybe you can convert with Ghostscript and get what you want. I doubt you can escape learning the PDF specification and doing lots of that yourself. All the tools I have found have just a basic fraction of Adobes standard.

Comment: @uldics I may be able to work around this.  The entries following the Yes/No statement will only be completed if Yes is selected.. So I'm looking at writing some tests to check what values are set.